# How to get input file 's data in old version browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I use `<input type="file"/>` to upload files and want to get file's message when I choose a file.
I can read it in console use:

```
console.log($("input[type=file]"));
```

but I don't know how to get `.files` here:

[image: file message]

for example,I want to get file size:95786 ,how to get it using JQuery?

**update：**

`this.files[0].size` dosen't work in IE7,I want more compatible function.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, you can use the `querySelector()` method to access the DOM elements.

This is how you should do it -

```
var files = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files;
console.log(files);
```

Comment: how to compatible in old version browser?

Comment: Thank you,but old version browser like `IE7`,can't use querySelector and can't recognize `.files`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

try the following:

```
//binds to onchange event of your input field
$('#myFile').bind('change', function() {

  //this.files[0].size gets the size of your file.
   console.log(this.files[0].size);

});
```

**Old browsers support**

Be aware that old browsers will return a null value for the previous this.files call, so accessing this.files[0] will raise an exception and you should check for File API support before using it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file size using

```
$('input[type=file]').bind('change', function() {
  console.log(this.files[0].size);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend checking out [the jQuery File Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). It enables easy access to loads of information about uploads, including [live upload speeds, bytes uploaded so far, and total upload size](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Extended-progress-information).